# Delegate.CreateDelegate - method arguments are incompatible

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

Given a`MethodInfo` for the following method

```
public class MyEffects
{
  public Task Test(object action, IDispatcher dispatcher)
  {
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}
```

Why does the following `CreateDelegate` code throw `System.ArgumentException: method arguments are incompatible`?

```
Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    type: typeof(Func<object, IDispatcher, Task>),
    method: discoveredEffect.MethodInfo);
```

As does this

```
Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    type: typeof(Func<object, object, IDispatcher, Task>),
    method: discoveredEffect.MethodInfo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to create to delegate to a non static method you have to provide a target using the [`CreateDelegate(Type, Object, MethodInfo)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=netframework-4.8#System_Delegate_CreateDelegate_System_Type_System_Object_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_) overload:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var method = typeof(MyEffects).GetMethod("Test");
        var obj = new MyEffects();
        var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, IDispatcher, Task>), obj, method);
        Console.WriteLine(del);
    }
}

public class MyEffects
{
  public Task Test(object action, IDispatcher dispatcher)
  {
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}

public interface IDispatcher {}
```

returns

> System.Func`3[System.Object,IDispatcher,System.Threading.Tasks.Task]

Comment: Ahh, I only tried the `firstArgument` overload with an additional object in the `Func`.

I see now though that I still get the same exception. This is because my delegate cannot possibly know the first argument type of `Test` so I need to specify my delegate argument type as `object`.

Is there a way around this?